# Unable to create Android kits using Qt Creator

Tags: android, qt

[image]I have followed the official documentation on how to install the prerequisites (Android sdk etc.) as shown in my screen shot below on a Windows 10 machine running Qt Creator 4.14.0.

[![Android settings in Qt Creator][2]][2]

However, the Android Kit is not detected when creating an Android project.

After hitting the 'Apply' button, this is how the kit section looks like:

[image]

Comment: What's the difference between your two screenshots? Can you click "Apply" and send a screenshot of the "Kits" section?

Comment: I have since deleted the extra image unnecessary image.

Comment: I don't understand where the Android kit comes from in your first screenshot. Did you create it manually?

Comment: Is there no message reported in QtCreator's messages tab?

Comment: So sorry about my screenshots. You are right the 'Android Kit' is the one I was trying to create manually. I will delete this screenshot in my post. Thanks

Comment: How do I access the 'QtCreators message tab'? I am new to Qt Creator and I have been looking around and can't find it. Where would it be?

Comment: The Message tab is visible at the bottom of the main GUI when options dialog is closed.

Comment: In the 'General messages' tab, i get the following message when Qt Creator starts before I even start using it: "2021-05-02T18:47:46 Clang Code Model: Error: The clangbackend executable "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\clangbackend.exe" could not be started (timeout after 10000ms)."

Comment: I get this sometimes, it should not prevent it from creating correctly the kit for Android.

Comment: Will you please manually create an Android Kit and then send me your screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a compatibility issue with all the tools you are trying to use, but it's hard to say if the message tab does not report any issue.

I use Qt Creator 4.12 with Qt 5.14.2, I zipped it [here](https://uptobox.com/kqas5qmlh0km).
I also zipped my SDK/JDK [here](https://uptobox.com/7s62ybaz9myr).

- Extract the first zip file to a folder on your local machine (let’s call it QTCREATOR_FOLDER)
- Extract the second zip file to a different folder
- Add copied JDK’s bin folder to your PATH variable
- Update all xml files from QTCREATOR_FOLDER\Tools\QtCreator\share\qtcreator\QtProject\qtcreator (android.xml, debuggers.xml, qtversion.xml, toolchains.xml, QtCreator.ini) to have all existing references to C:/Android2/QtCreator5_12 be replaced by QTCREATOR_FOLDER (with slashs, no backslashs)
- Open QtCreator: QTCREATOR_FOLDER\Tools\QtCreator\bin\qtcreator.exe, go to “Outils, Options, Appareils mobiles, Android” and specify the paths to copied JDK and SDK folders. Ignore OpenSSL errors. Clic “Apply”. Close and re-open QtCreator.
- Go to “Outils, Options, Kits”, an auto-detected “Android for armeabi-v7a,arm64-v8a,x86,x86_64 (Clang Qt 5.14.2 for Android)” should appear.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, I will be closing this question thanks to your answer. However, I was not able to download the files you sent me because my anti-virus reported virus activity on the download sites. Instead, I uninstalled Qt and downgraded to Qt 5.14.2 which is probably a pity because I might be missing out on the functionality of Qt 5.15.2. Thanks for your unrelenting help - have a nice day keep observing social distancing and other protocols.

Comment: @Khandakhulu: Then it worked with 5.14.2 version you downloaded?

Comment: Yes it is working  on 5.14.2 - I now have auto detected Android and UWP kits. I am keen though to find a 'clean' machine on which to try the latest version of Qt. Thanks for reminding me about the bounty. It is the first time I am using this bounty thing and was not quite sure about how it works. I have awarded it to you I hope it shows on your side.